# VBA Efficiency for Larger Data Sets

Tags: excel, vba

I created an Excel spreadsheet that allows users to input data. Then it takes formulas from a seperate tab, and pastes them in to the data set tab. It then sorts all of them in a specific order which is needed for the process it is used for.

I have tried to increase the efficiency by turning off automatic calcs and only calculating when I need to, then pasting values after that. I have also turned off screen updating, status bar, and enable events. I think these are some of the low hanging fruit.

It works pretty well for smaller datasets (say 25K rows and smaller) but it can really get bogged down with larger ones. I have one in particular that is 48K rows and it often will just end up freezing my Excel.

Any spots jumping out that could be altered to increase efficiency?

--

```
Worksheets("Update Indicator").Visible = True
Sheets("Update Indicator").Range("B1") = 1
Dim LossSort As Workbook
Dim WC As Worksheet
Dim WC_Form As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double

StartTime = Timer

Set LossSort = ThisWorkbook
Set WC = LossSort.Sheets("WC Losses")
Set WC_Form = LossSort.Sheets("WC Formulas")

If WC.AutoFilterMode Then
    WC.AutoFilterMode = False
End If

lastRow = WC.Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Code to help speed up macro
With Application
 .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 .ScreenUpdating = False
 .DisplayStatusBar = False
 .EnableEvents = False
End With

    Calculate
          
    'Test if the value in cell U2 is blank/empty
    If IsEmpty(WC.Range("W2").Value) = True Then
      MsgBox "No WC Losses Available"
      Exit Sub
    Else
    End If

    'Set Original Order
    WC.Range("BH2") = 1
    WC.Range("BH2:BH" & lastRow).DataSeries , xlDataSeriesLinear
    
    'Copy formulas from WC Formulas tab to WC Losses
    WC_Form.Range("A2:U2").Copy Destination:=WC.Range("A2:U" & lastRow)
    WC_Form.Range("AX2:BG2").Copy Destination:=WC.Range("AX2:BG" & lastRow)
   
    'Calculate
    WC.Calculate
    
    'Apply formatting across the dataset
    WC_Form.Range("L2:AM2").Copy
    WC.Range("L2:O" & lastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    
    'Sort by Acc Desc and Claim# then by Closed No Pay, Loss Date, State
    
        With Sheets("WC Losses").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Cells
            .Sort Key1:=Range("Z1"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                Key2:=Range("V1"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
        End With
    
            With Sheets("WC Losses").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Cells
            .Sort Key1:=Range("K1"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                Key2:=Range("W1"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                Key3:=Range("X1"), Order3:=xlAscending, _
                Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
        End With
      
    'Paste values over formulas
    WC.Calculate
    
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = WC.Range("A2:T" & lastRow)
    WC.Range("A2").Resize(rng1.Rows.Count, rng1.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng1.Cells.Value
    
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Set rng2 = WC.Range("AX2:BG" & lastRow)
    WC.Range("AX2").Resize(rng2.Rows.Count, rng2.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng2.Cells.Value
       
    Sheets("Update Indicator").Range("C5").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Update Indicator").Range("B5")
    Sheets("Update Indicator").Calculate
    Sheets("Update Indicator").Range("B5").Copy
    Sheets("Update Indicator").Range("B5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Worksheets("Update Indicator").Visible = False

finish:

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

With Application
 .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 .ScreenUpdating = True
 .DisplayStatusBar = True
 .EnableEvents = True
End With

    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
    MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation
```

Comment: When you step through your code (using `F8`), which line do you typically see the biggest slowdown?

Comment: Mostly the formula pasting and sorting so I think Frank's suggestions below can definitely be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by formatting your data as a Table and allowing it to manage your formulas.  That way you avoid all the VBA you're using to copy and paste your formulas.

You could also try using Power Query to handle the formulas and sorting and avoid most of the VBA you're using.

Also, if you're going to turn off calc, screenupdating, events etc., you've got to have error handling to make sure that is your code fails, they all get reset back to their defaults.  Otherwise, you can end with Excel in a REALLY bad state.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The error handling thing is interesting and not something I ever thought about. The file can get pretty unstable when I am doing testing so this is probably what you mean by a "REALLY bad state".